# Laravel including /index.php/ in url

Tags: apache, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

When I run the method `url('/assets/js/jquery.firefly-0.3-min.js')`, it comes out with this url: `/index.php/assets/js/jquery.firefly-0.3-min.js`. Any idea how that can be?

Note: I am running apache behind nginx, if that can have anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL::asset('assets/js/jquery.firefly[...]')
```